# jQuery - update values in all checked checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

My problem is that I have a table with multiple checkboxes and few buttons. Each checkbox have some value (number). What I'm trying to achieve is to could manipulate values in all checked checkboxes using buttons. When I click on the button than values in all selected checkboxes should increase/decrease (depend from clicked button).

I have so far this:

http://jsfiddle.net/5Et7g

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            var count = 0,
                newVal = parseInt($(this).val());

            $("#increase").click(function () {
                for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    count += 1;
                    if (newVal >= 90) {
                        newVal = 100;
                        $("#increase").prop('disabled', true);
                    } else {
                        newVal += 10;
                        $("#increase").prop('disabled', false);
                    }
                    console.log(newVal)
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I don't know how to update old values with those new (increased).

Comment: Why is your `click` event inside the `change` event? Is the `change` event even required in your case?

Comment: what is use case that you need to change value of a checkbox? Have you tried using `val()` ?

Comment: @Palash Mondal It's counter of buttons clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For increasing and decreasing values, you can use jQuery `val` method's callback function.

```
$("#increase, #decrease").click(function() {
    var num = this.id === 'increase' ? 10 : -10; 
    $('input[type=checkbox]').val(function(_, value){
        return +value + num;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NQaqr/

Regarding disabling the buttons: Since you have 1 increase/decrease button for all the elements you can't properly disable the button unless you have 1 button for each checkbox. For example one new value is 88, and another 100, I'm not sure in which case the button should be disabled/re-enabled.

Update: If you only want to increase/decrease values of the checked checkboxes, you can use `:checked` selector:

```
$("#increase, #decrease").click(function () {
    var num = this.id === 'increase' ? 10 : -10;
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').val(function (i, value) {
        var newVal = +value + num;
        if (newVal > 100) newVal = 100;
        else if (newVal < 0) newVal = 0;

        return newVal;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gRUrH/

Comment: Good point about buttons. I wanted to button be disabled when after x clicks of button value will reach 100 - it works when only one value is updated at a time but not when I'm updating multiple values.

Comment: In this case button should be disabled when any of checkbox updating values will reach 100.

Comment: It's actually the only working solution BUT even when I uncheck one of checkboxes it's still updating all.

Comment: @AnnaAccond So when one or more checkbox(es) with value more than or equal to 100 exist(s) the `#increase` button should be disabled? I have updated the answer for `checked` checkboxes. (I'll update the answer regarding disabling/enabling checkboxes based on your answer to my question.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with, hope it helps:

```
$("#increase").click(function() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            var newVal = parseInt(this.value); 
            if (this.value >= 90) {
                newVal = 100;
                $("#increase").prop('disabled', true);
            } else {
                //do other stuff
                newVal += 10;
                $("#increase").prop('disabled', false); 
            }
            console.log(newVal);
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Et7g/2/

Comment: There's one more requirement: _values in all selected checkboxes should increase/decrease_

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the first `change` event. This will run whenever you actually change the value of one of your check boxes. What you want is to bind the event to the click action of your button. So you want something like:

```
$("#increase").click(function() {
  $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(idx, input) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val >= 90) {
      val = 100;
      $("#increase").prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      val += 10;
      $("#increase").prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

This should do what you're after

Comment: There's one more requirement: _values in all selected checkboxes should increase/decrease_

Comment: Which is what it's doing? It's looping over each selected checkbox and changing the value. Not of the other checkboxes.